# Persisting or writing spark dataset to OrientDB using java

Tags: java, apache-spark, orientdb2.2

How can I write a Spark dataset to OrientDB using java?

I already read data from OrientDB using Orient Java JDBC driver, but I am unable to persist the same dataset into OrientDB.

Code:

```
public void readAndWriteData(SparkSession spark, Map<String, String> dbProps, Properties destinationDb) {
    Dataset<Row> tableDataset = spark.read().format("jdbc").options(dbProps).load();
    tableDat‌​aset.show();
    tableDat‌​aset.createOrReplace‌​TempView("TEMP_V");

    D‌​ataset<Row> tableDataset1 = spark.sql("SELECT NAME FROM TEMP_V");
    tableDataset1.show();
    tableDataset1.write().format("‌​org.apache.spark.ori‌​entdb.documents")
            .option("dburl", "jdbc:orient:REMOTE:localhost/testdb")
            .option("user", "root")
            .option("password", "root")
            .option("class", "Test")
            .mode(SaveMode.Append).save();
}
```

Here i am getting error as

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection Exception Occurred: Error on opening database 'jdbc:orient:REMOTE:localhost/testdb'
```

can you please help me on this error. I have used same db connection for reading and persisting

Comment: You can simply use the spark-orientDB connector for this, By using this connector you can simply persist the whole rdd into the db for more info please check below links

http://orientdb.com/spark-orientdb/
http://orientdb.com/spark/
https://github.com/metreta/spark-orientdb-connector

Comment: Hi, Sandeep
 the following i written the following code

Comment: public void readAndWriteData(SparkSession spark, Map<String, String> dbProps, Properties destinationDb){Dataset<Row> tableDataset = spark.read().format("jdbc").options(dbProps).load();tableDataset.show();tableDataset.createOrReplaceTempView("TEMP_V");Dataset<Row> tableDataset1 = spark.sql("SELECT NAME FROM TEMP_V");tableDataset1.show();tableDataset1.write().format("org.apache.spark.orientdb.documents") .option("dburl", "jdbc:orient:REMOTE:localhost/testdb") .option("user", "root")        .option("password", "root") .option("class", "Test")        .mode(SaveMode.Append).save(); }

Comment: Here i am getting error as 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection Exception Occurred: Error on opening database 'jdbc:orient:REMOTE:localhost/testdb'

can  you please help me on this error. i used same db connection for reading and persisting

Comment: At the moment of writing the orientdb's jdbc driver isn't able to persist a spark dataset. It should be patched to compatible with spark. It is, although, able to read from orientdb and load a dataset. Please use the spark connector or open an issue for jdbc if needed